# Seting NSString variable loops

Tags: objective-c, variables

I have NSSTring variable declared in my .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currencyCode;
```

In my .m file I'm trying to set this variable using following method:

```
-(void)setCurrencyCode:(NSString *)code {
    self.currencyCode = code;
    [currencyButton setTitle:currencyCode forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Program loops on `self.currencyCode = code;`

`currencyCode` is nil and `code` isn't

What is happening here?

Comment: @giorashc He means getting into infinite recursion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.currencyCode = x;
```

is a synonym for

```
[self setCurrencyCode:x];
```

So you are calling the setter in an infinite loop. Use this instead:

```
_currencyCode = code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement this.  Synthesize it. Set the UI label in an IBAction method or another method.